# Substituting sweetened condensed milk for evaporated milk

Tags: candy

I am making caramel. The recipe calls for 2 - 12oz. cans of evaporated milk. I want to use sweetened condensed milk. Do I use the same amount?

Comment: What's the recipe you're using? (Edit your post to add the recipe to it, rather than just adding a link.) And why do you want to change the recipe... do you not have evaporated milk, or are you trying to get different results?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between the two products is that sweetened condensed milk has added sugar.  This could be a problem for your recipe.  Evaporated milk, since it is concentrated (about 60% of the water is removed) is already a bit sweeter. When sweetened condensed milk is made, more sugar is added to evaporated milk, leaving the final product in the 40 - 45% sugar range.  So, the answer to your question will, in large part, depend on your recipe.  There are caramel recipes online that make use of sweetened condensed milk.  You might just start off with one of those.

Comment: There are online recipes that use sweetened condensed milk  as the only ingredient to make caramel. Some recipes even suggest making the caramel in the sealed can of sweetened condensed milk which seems foolish to me.

Comment: @MaxW you can safely cook a sealed can of sweetened condensed milk in a pressure cooker to create dulce de leche.  See: https://www.hippressurecooking.com/dulce-de-leche-pressure-cooked-condensed-milk/